# How to autofill name of columns in sql query using python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pyqt5

I'm working on `GUI` application using `PyQt5` that will print the script that compare two tables. User need to input name of first and second table and also name of columns. I compare two tables using such `sql` query:

```
select table_1.<name_of_first_column>,
table_1.<name_of_second_column>,
<etc>,
cast('<name_of_first_table>' as varchar(100)) as SOURCE_ from <name_of_first_table> as table_1
left join <name_of_second_table> as table_2 on 1=1 
and((table_1.<name_of_first_column> = table_2.<name_of_first_column>) or (table_1.<name_of_first_column> is null and table_2.<name_of_first_column> is null))
and((table_1.<name_of_second_column> = table_2.<name_of_second_column>) or (table_1.<name_of_second_column> is null and table_2.<name_of_second_column> is null))
<etc>
union all 
select table_2.<name_of_first_column>,
table_2.<name_of_second_column>,
<etc>,
cast('<name_of_second_table>' as varchar(100)) as SOURCE_ from <name_of_second_table> as table_2
left join <name_of_first_table> as table_1 on 1=1 
and((table_1.<name_of_first_column> = table_2.<name_of_first_column>) or (table_1.<name_of_first_column> is null and table_2.<name_of_first_column> is null))
and((table_1.<name_of_second_column> = table_2.<name_of_second_column>) or (table_1.<name_of_second_column> is null and table_2.<name_of_second_column> is null))
<etc>
```

I filled names of tables, but also i need to fill names of columns, but i dont know how to implement it.
Here is the code of my programm:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(496, 491)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.textEdit_columns = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_columns.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 241, 151))
        self.textEdit_columns.setObjectName("textEdit_columns")

        self.button_ok = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_ok.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 430, 111, 31))
        self.button_ok.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85, 170, 0);")
        self.button_ok.setObjectName("button_ok")

        self.label_name_columns = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_name_columns.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 10, 111, 31))
        self.label_name_columns.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);")
        self.label_name_columns.setObjectName("label_name_columns")

        self.label_1_name = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_1_name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 10, 121, 31))
        self.label_1_name.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);")
        self.label_1_name.setObjectName("label_1_name")

        self.label_2_name = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2_name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 100, 131, 31))
        self.label_2_name.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2_name.setObjectName("label_2_name")

        self.lineEdit_1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 50, 171, 41))
        self.lineEdit_1.setObjectName("lineEdit_1")

        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 140, 171, 41))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")

        self.label_name_columns_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_name_columns_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 230, 111, 31))
        self.label_name_columns_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 127);")
        self.label_name_columns_2.setObjectName("label_name_columns_2")

        self.textEdit_script = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_script.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 270, 451, 151))
        self.textEdit_script.setObjectName("textEdit_script")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.add_functions()
        self.button_ok.clicked.connect(self.copy_text)

    def add_functions(self):
        self.button_ok.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write(self.lineEdit_1.text()))
        self.button_ok.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write(self.lineEdit_2.text()))
        self.button_ok.clicked.connect(lambda: self.preview())

    def write(self, word):
        print(word)

    def copy_text(self):
        text = self.textEdit_columns.toPlainText()
        self.write(text)

    def preview(self):
        lineEdit_1 = self.lineEdit_1.text()
        lineEdit_2 = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.textEdit_script.setText(""" select table_1.col_1,
table_1.col_2,
cast('""" +  lineEdit_1 + """' as varchar(100)) as SOURCE_ from """ +  lineEdit_1 + """ as table_1
left join """ +  lineEdit_2 + """ as table_2 on 1=1 
and((table_1.col_1 = table_2.col_1) or (table_1.col_1 is null and table_2.col_1 is null))
and((table_1.col_2 = table_2.col_2) or (table_1.col_2 is null and table_2.col_2 is null))
union all 
select table_2.col_1),
table_2.col_2,
cast('""" +  lineEdit_2 + """' as varchar(100)) as SOURCE_ from """ +  lineEdit_2 + """ as table_2
left join """ +  lineEdit_1 + """ as table_1 on 1=1 
and((table_1.col_1 = table_2.col_1) or (table_1.col_1 is null and table_2.col_1 is null))
and((table_1.col_2 = table_2.col_2) or (table_1.col_2 is null and table_2.col_2 is null));

select cast('""" +  lineEdit_1 + """' as VARCHAR(100)) as SOURSE, count(*) from """ +  lineEdit_1 + """
union all
select cast('""" +  lineEdit_1 + """' as VARCHAR(100)) as SOURSE, count(*) """ +  lineEdit_2 + """""")

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Compare of tables"))
        self.button_ok.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OK"))
        self.label_name_columns.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">Name of columns</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_1_name.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">Name of first table</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_2_name.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">Name of second table</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_name_columns_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">Script</span></p></body></html>"))


if name == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally implemented it, also i added 'order by' to sort tables. I hope my solution will be useful to someone

```
      def preview(self):
        lineEdit_1 = self.lineEdit_1.text()
        lineEdit_2 = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        lineEdit_3 = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        columns = self.textEdit_columns.toPlainText()
        numb_of_columns = len(columns.split())
        col = columns.split()
        # print(col)

        quer_col_1 = ''
        for i in range(numb_of_columns):
            quer_col_1 += """table_1.""" + col[i] + ',\n'
        # print(quer_col_1)

        quer_col_2 = ''
        for i in range(numb_of_columns):
            quer_col_2 += """table_2.""" + col[i] + ',\n'
        # print(quer_col_2)

        quer = ''
        for i in range(numb_of_columns):
            quer += """and((table_1.""" + col[i] + """ = table_2.""" + col[i] + """) or (table_1.""" + col[
                i] + """ is null and table_2.""" + col[i] + """ is null))""" + "\n"
        # print(quer)

        self.textEdit_script.setText(""" select """ + quer_col_1 + """
    cast('""" + lineEdit_1 + """' as varchar(100)) as SOURCE_ from """ + lineEdit_1 + """ as table_1
    left join """ + lineEdit_2 + """ as table_2 on 1=1 
    """ + quer + """
    union all 
    select """ + quer_col_2 + """
    cast('""" + lineEdit_2 + """' as varchar(100)) as SOURCE_ from """ + lineEdit_2 + """ as table_2
    left join """ + lineEdit_1 + """ as table_1 on 1=1 
    """ + quer + """
    order by """ + lineEdit_3 + """;

    select cast('""" + lineEdit_1 + """' as VARCHAR(100)) as SOURSE, count(*) from """ + lineEdit_1 + """
    union all
    select cast('""" + lineEdit_2 + """' as VARCHAR(100)) as SOURSE, count(*) from """ + lineEdit_2 + """""")
```